# Two divs side by side, right div fixed width

Tags: css, html, css-float

I know this has been asked a million times before but i still can't seem to find the answer (most questions seem to be the opposite of what i want not the same).

I have two divs say #left and #right.  #right has fixed dimensions 150px x 50px.  I want #left to expand and fill the remaining space and #right to be on the very right of the screen.  I have tried floating them in different ways and also setting display: inline-block; but i still cant seem to nail it.  All the articles i've read are about the left div being fixed and the right one growing.  I tried reversing what i read but it always leads to the #left div floating around #right. What i mean by this is, my #left div will with shrink to its smallest (inline-block) or it will display the first 50px up to the #right then the rest of #left will tuck under #right rather than staying flush.

I hope this makes sense. It's kind of hard to explain.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write like this:

```
.right{
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 float:right;
 background:red;
}
.left{
 height:150px;
 background:green;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="right">fixed</div>
<div class="left">auto</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/TW4dn/

Comment: Perfect, i actually tried this but as mines is a few divs it didn't quite work. Wrapper div sorted it.  Silly me, but still the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to be able to do this if the HTML code has to right div second and you can't change the code, only the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<div class="right" style="clear:right">
```